# sails: TypeError: path must be a string

Tags: json, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to read xls file to json format by using `xls-to-json` node module 
 while sending a file path it shows an error like path must be a string

I'm Using below snippet

```
var fs = uploadedFiles[0].fd;
//fs is a file path                                                     
node_xj = require("xls-to-json");
node_xj({
          input:fs, 

        }, function(err, result)
           {
                if(err) 
                {
                   console.error(err);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
```

Error

```
    fs.js:430
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
          ^
TypeError: path must be a string
```

please help to fix this issue.

Comment: What does `typeof uploadedFiles[0].fd` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer based on `xls-to-json` documentation itself. Let's imagine you have action that accepts file as input file. Output is `json` file in the same folder. So when you are sending a file via HTTP request, you can upload that file with `upload` method. `files` is an array with uploaded files and you can get path to file via `fd` property.

So this example should work just fine:

```
// api/controllers/AnyController.js
var path = require('path');
var xlsToJson = require('xls-to-json');

module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    req.file('param_name').upload(function(error, files) {
      if (error) return res.serverError(error);

      xlsToJson({
        input: files[0].fd,
        output: path.resolve('./', 'output.json')
      }, function(error, result) {
        if (error) return res.serverError(error);
        res.ok(result);
      });
    });
  }
};
```